# How to store a huge static/immutable String Set that needs only the 'contains' operations in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, set

I have a huge list of Strings (8 to 10 million). They are Wikipedia page titles. After creating a Set-like data structure over these strings, the only operation I need is `boolean contains(String str)`.

The straightforward way is to just use a `HashSet`, `TreeSet` or something alike (in Java, for example).

Is there a data structure more fitted for this use case?

PS: We can't use bloom filters, we don't want to deal with false positives.

Comment: And I was about to say ...bloom filters

Answer (score 1):

If you care more about saving space than constant-time `contains()`, and there is a lot of overlap in the stored strings, a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might help. In that case, `contains(str)` would be `O(n)` where `n` is the length of `str`.

Comment: Nice suggestion.  Note that this is effectively constant-time if you think about it (the running time does not grow with the size of the collection, and the entries are bounded in size).

Comment: Trie is actually a nice suggestion. I'm only a little afraid the linear complexity on the `str` might hurt performance. The contains(str) operation will run hundreds of times each second.

Comment: @Felipe Hummel, can you cache the contains(str) results?

Comment: @TonyRad I guess so. But a cache + Trie could potentially use the same memory a simple HashSet would.

Comment: @FelipeHummel I wouldn't be so concerned. Even though `contains()` takes longer, the longer `str` is, it's overall a _very_ simple algorithm. Even hashing a string for a `HashSet#contains()` has to first compute a string's `hashCode()`, which is `O(n)`. Give it a shot.

Comment: Will Bloom Filter + Trie a possible solution? Both is effective in storage space.  Bloom Filter for testing negative, use Trie on positive results to get rid of false positive